# Finding a generalized form for this series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While i was just playing around with series i came across this one,

$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty[\frac{k}{k-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{k-\frac{1}{2}}{k}-\frac{k+\frac{1}{2}}{k} - \frac{k}{k-\frac{1}{2}}]
$$

Which simplified nicely into

$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^3-k} = \ln(4)-1
$$

Then i wondered the results would be if i changed the $\frac{1}{2}$ into $\frac{1}{n}$

I simplified the initial summation to

$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^3 k^3 - nk}
$$

Then i found a few of the results of the summations,

$S_2 = \ln(4)-1$

$S_3 = \ln(3)-1$

$S_4 = \frac{\ln(8)}{2}-1$

$S_5 = \ln(\frac{5}{8} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{8})(\sqrt{5}+1)-\sqrt{5}\ln(\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}) + \frac{1}{10}[\ln(\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}) + 4\ln(10)-10]$

$S_6 = \frac{\ln(432)}{6}-1$

My interest is piqued and i would love to see a generalized form of what $S_n$ would yield and how one would go about finding this.

Comment: What happened at $n = 5$ ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\;\psi\left(1+\frac 1n\right)+\psi\left(1-\frac 1n\right)+2\gamma\,$ using [the expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula) :
$$\psi(1+x)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac x{k\,(k+x)}$$
For practical cases see [Gauss' result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem).

Comment: I think that there is a typo with the variables in the summation

Comment: @Eric Corrected. Fine continuation anyway!

Comment: Wow this actually works out perfectly haha

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Raymond Manzoni's answer, i have found the generalized form

Since

$$\psi(1+x) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{k(k+x)}$$

$$
\psi(1+\frac{1}{n})+\psi(1-\frac{1}{n})+2\gamma = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk(k+\frac{1}{n})}-\frac{1}{nk(k-\frac{1}{n})}
$$

$$
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2k}{n^2k^4-k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{n^2 k^3-k} \therefore
$$

$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n^3k^3-nk} = -\frac{\psi(1+\frac{1}{n})+\psi(1-\frac{1}{n})+2\gamma}{n}
$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks for the catch

Comment: Note that the Gauss formula will provide an answer without the special function $\psi$ (using $\psi(1+1/n)=\psi(1/n)+n$).

Comment: $$S_n=-\frac{H_{-\frac{1}{n}}+H_{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$